# Is the principle of relativity correct?

Tags: inertial-frames, observers, galilean-relativity

Imagine two platforms side by side. The only difference is one of them is moving while the other is at rest. If a person wants to transition from the moving one to the stationary one he has to jump onto the other platform then run for sometime in the direction of his initial  motion. But consider this, if he is initially standing on stationary platform and wants to be on the moving one which way should he run? We could think he must move in the direction the other platform is moving until he reaches its velocity because only then he will be at rest with respect to it and then he should jump. Now, let us invoke the principle of relativity which says we cannot distiguish between two frames which are in relative motion with constant velocity (not relatively acclerating). That means we cannot call one platform as moving and the other one as being at rest. Now since he is actually in the rest frame from his point of view we can let him consider the one in which he is in as the moving one and the other being at rest which is allowed because by the principle of relativity there is no absolute motion. Then he should run in the direction in which he is thinking he is moving after jumping which would be opposite to the direction he would have jumped in if he thought he was at rest. So, which direction should he jump? I am a beginner to physics so please don't be rude if I am being wrong or just plain stupid. So basically is principle of relativity wrong or is it just merely my understanding of it that's incorrect?

Comment: Relativity is simply the consequence of an empty background. So if you are imagining this happening in air, then relativity does not hold.

Comment: *Is the principle of relativity correct?* In addition to being correct, it is one of the foundations of physics.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that the platforms are sufficiently heavy that a change of momentum due to a person jumping onto does not need to be accounted in the motion of the platform.

Relativity tells the following:
If you compare two systems and in both systems the net forces are exactly the same - especially no Coriolis forces, no centripetal forces and the like - then both systems are moving relative to each other with at most a constant velocity.

You can also ask:
In what frame does the runners momentum not change upon arriving at the platform in order to not excert an additional force that is not universal (he is not excerted to a temporary force in his own system)

Why to ask this?

Because relativity asserts that in each frame that is not accelerated, Newton's axioms must be valid. Especially a constant momentum has to be equal to zero net force.
So the runner has to move in such a way that after jumping his momentum does not change.

If he ran in the opposite direction compared to the direction of the moving object, his momentum would change by twice his velocity, excerting a force on him temporarily due to his inertia in order to be at rest with the object he is jumping onto.

You might get confused because it might be tempting to think about cancelling out the velocity of the runner and the velocity of the moving platform, but the quest is not to nullify momentum but the quest is to have two systems in which physics work equally or differently put: To have two systems in which the laws of motion are governed by the same forces.

This is the reason why you cannot compare physics on a rotating platform to phyisics on a non rotating platform becuase on the rotating platform Coriolisforces appear, which are completely relative forces only visible in the rotating system. So in the rotating system you have a governing force that does not appear in the non-rotating system.

Answer (score -3):

You made a good point. I think the problem can be asked in another way (correct me if I'm wrong):

Consider two people one stationary and one in a spaceship moving with velocity. If we agree on the principles then the moving one should experience it's time slower than the other one which is stationary. Now, WHICH one is actually stationary? from the perspective of one the other is moving away with a relative velocity. So which clock is actually moving slower?

I think there's a good resemblance between your thought experiment and mine. You seem to not be able to decide which one is moving therefore cannot predict what is to be happening with clocks (or what you should do after jumping)! But that's okay.

In these kinds of question regarding special relativity one should note that **we have to choose a reference frame and stick to it!** This plays an essential role in dealing with these thought experiments. Now for my clock example if you really need to know which one was moving, then you have to gather them in one place and then measure their clock together (which need either one of them to change its velocity) but if you do so then your dealing with another kind of problem.

Comment: Yeah it somehow resembles your thought and both of them resemble the twin paradox in someway but the twin paradox can be resolved by acceleration (so far as I know relativity. Correct me if I am wrong here). So how do we resolve this? Or can we even resolve?

Comment: @HazimAhmed No actually, I think you are insisting on saying "What happens really?" which is not a correct thing to ask in special relativity. First you have to say in which reference frame are we working. In the twin paradox (or your experiment) we can say that each of them calculates time dilation with respect to the other. if we really one to get that straight then the two would have to meet each other  (as I explained above) which causes acceleration, which can be felt. Therefore we can actually sense if we are the one moving or not.

Comment: @HazimAhmed In both reference frames that your experiment have one would imagine him/herself stationary and the other plane moving. Therefore I don't see any paradoxes. If you want to make sure which one is in fact moving , you have no chance but to accelerate one of planes! which I guess is impossible in your case, thus we are never able to tell if one is in constant motion or stationary. It's all Relative :)

Comment: @ KidA So all observers think they are at rest. Is that what we need to resolve this.

Comment: @HazimAhmed Yep, You need to choose only one reference frame and then work your physics, you cannot jump around different system and try to stay consistent at the same time.

Comment: Ok thank you for the clarification

Comment: @HazimAhmed Have fun learning ;) 
Consider Checking the answer if you are convinced.